# .NET Core 5. Error Handling Middleware vs UseExceptionHandler

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

I have seen some code samples using a error handling middleware like

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }
```

I have also seen code using

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(HandleException());
```

Are they both the same? Is there a preference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latter option is a "premade" middleware for you to use that comes with some options that you can modify.

If these options are enough for you, you can just use it, otherwise you'll need to write a custom middleware.

I actually prefer a custom middleware since exception handling becomes very explicit and a bit easier to understand, as well as residing fully in it's own class.

Comment: Also makes it easier for "unit" testing.